# How to create playlist for jplayer using xml

Tags: xml, jplayer

How to create playlist for jplayer using xml file and also i can dynamically add new items through ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

> **SOLUTION 1**

You can use the following code as the starting point:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var cssSelector = { jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1", cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1" };
   var options = { swfPath: "../js", supplied: "ogg, mp3" };
   var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist(cssSelector, [], options);

   $.get("xml_audio.php", {}, function (xml){
      $('Track', xml).each(function (i){
         var title = $(this).attr('title');
         var track_name = $(this).attr('track_name');

         myPlaylist.add({ 
            'title': title, 
            'mp3': 'audio/' + track_name + '.mp3', 
            'ogg': 'audio/' + track_name + '.ogg' 
         });
      });
   });
});
```

> **SOLUTION 2**

Alternatively, please take a look at [jPlayer Jukebox add-on](http://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jplayer-jukebox/). It is based on [jPlayer Playlist add-on](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/) but adds extra functionality, such as ability to scan the page for media links and make them playable. It now supports playlists in [XSPF](http://xspf.xiph.org/) format.

[image: jPlayer Jukebox add-on]